# Почему в AndroidStudio в Preview цвет фона один, а по факту другой?

Tags: android

Почему в IntelijIdea в Preview цвет фона белый, как я и указал в `android:background="#fff"`, а в эмуляторе и на телефоне черный?

Что на это может повлиять ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файле манифета, в тегах активити было указано 
`android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme"`, когда убрал - все заработало. 
Странно ппц.